# Novel where a predator comes into being

Tags: story-identification, novel

Novel where alien enters room through wall and invites author to publish all through galaxy and predator chases him to satisfy a universal law

Answer (score 9):

**Novel where a predator comes into being**

[*Dimension of Miracles*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9687), a 1968 novel by [Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley). Maybe you will recognize one of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?9687). Plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Miracles):

> Thanks to a computer error, Tom Carmody, an unlucky [civil servant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_service), wins the main prize of the Galactic Lottery. Being a human from the Earth, he doesn't possess galactic status and shouldn't even be eligible. However, he obtains the Prize before the mistake is found out and is allowed to keep it. That's when his adventure begins, since, not being a space-traveling creature, he has no [homing instinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homing_(biology)) that can guide him back to Earth, and so the galactic lottery organizers cannot transport him home. At the same time, his removal from his home environment has caused, by the 'universal law of predation', a predatory entity to spring into existence that perpetually pursues and aims to destroy him. So Carmody is forced to be on the run, and with the help of his Prize meets several well-meaning (but usually not very competent) aliens that attempt to find where, when and which Earth he belongs on. He ends up transporting from Earth to Earth: different phases and realities of his planet, which of course, is not in the time or condition he expects it to be.

**Novel where alien enters room through wall**

The alien messenger does not come through the wall, but appears inexplicably in the middle of Carmody's living room:

> A moment later there was a clap of thunder and a flash of lightning from the middle of the living room. Carmody sat upright and clutched at his throat for no particular reason. The thunder rumbled for several seconds, then was replaced by a paean of trumpets. Carmody hastily removed his feet from the marble table. The trumpets ceased, and were replaced by a brave skirling of bagpipes. There was another flash of lightning, and a man appeared in the middle of the brilliance.

**and invites author to publish all through galaxy**

No, there is nothing about publishing, and the protagonist is not an author, he is some kind of office worker:

> It had been a typically unsatisfactory day. Carmody had gone to the office, flirted mildly with Miss Gibson, disagreed respectfully with Mr. Wainbock, and spent fifteen minutes with Mr. Blackwell, discussing the outlook for the football Giants.

The Messenger has come to tell Carmody he's won a prize:

> Then I shall explain; you, Mr. Carmody, have won a Prize in the Intergalactic Sweepstakes. Your coefficients were pulled by the Random Selector for Part IV, Class 32 Life-Forms. Your Prize—a very handsome Prize, I believe—is waiting for you at Galactic Center."

**and predator chases him to satisfy a universal law**

> "Your predator was born out of a personification and solidification of universal law. This predator can feed exclusively and solely on you. The creature is shaped as a respondent and complement to your characteristics. Even without seeing it, we can know that its jaws are shaped to bite Carmodys, its limbs are articulated to seize and grasp Carmodys, its stomach has the peculiar and unique ability to digest Carmodys, and its personality is designed to take advantage of the Carmodic personality."