# 1960s era story about writer in parallel universe being stalked by predator

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, metaphysics

I am looking for the title of a novel about a writer approached to publish books in alternative universes. As he has no natural predators one always comes into existence in each universe visited.

Comment: Happily, this question was just asked. Let me link the answer.\

Comment: Nota bene: Questions tagged [tag:story-identification] should not be closed as duplicates unless they both have accepted answers. (Even though this is very obviously a duplicate of the linked question).

Answer (score 3):

### [*Dimension of Miracles*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/668634.Dimension_of_Miracles)

This is probably the same story referred to in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128340/novel-where-a-predator-comes-into-being).

As indicated in the other question:

> "Your predator was born out of a personification and solidification of
>   universal law. This predator can feed exclusively and solely on you.
>   The creature is shaped as a respondent and complement to your
>   characteristics."